# Function dictionary and objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make some home automation and control via a midi pad in python3.
I also try to make the configuration of the pad outside the main code.
To make it simple I have 3 different files.

I built a SpotifyAPI.py whose structure is a bit like this:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, arguments):
        do_stuff()

    def play(self):
        do_stuff()
```

I then have a FunctionMap.py:

```
import SpotifyAPI
function = {
    "SpotifyPlay" : SpotifyAPI.Player.play
}
```

I then want to call the play function of the player object in a main.py:

```
import SpotifyAPI
from FunctionMap.py import *
SpotifyPlayer = SpotifyAPI.Player(arguments)
SpotifyPlayer.(function["SpotifyPlay"]) #something like that
```

Is it possible? If yes how? If not do you have an idea how to approach it differently?

Comment: Yes, the syntax would be `function["SpotifyPlay"](SpotifyPlayer)`

Comment: @PeterWood Actually makes a lot of sense.
Thank you a lot!

Comment: You’re very welcome

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @PeterWood for the answer:

```
function["SpotifyPlay"](SpotifyPlayer)
```